# Parsing string to Enum C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a following enum

```
[Flags]
public enum CreditCardType
{
None = 0x0,
[EnumLabel("Visa")]                Visa           = 0x1,
[EnumLabel("Maestro")]             Maestro        = 0x2,
[EnumLabel("Master Card")]         Master         = 0x4,

}
```

The user replies to these options as string. I am trying to convert string to enum like

```
CreditCardType=(CreditCardType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CreditCardType),"Visa");
```

On this I get the following error. Requested value "Visa" was not found.

Where I am wrong? Please help.

Comment: Are you using `Enum` or `enum` in the type definition?

Comment: There is no error in the conversion code you've shown. I'm guessing your real problem is something like: `(CreditCardType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CreditCardType),"Master Card")`.

Comment: This works for me as expected. I'd suspect the input. Does the code you pasted compile and run for you, or are you simplifying it from code that doesn't work?

Comment: Actually I am writing this code for my SharePoint feature. It compiles fine but give error on feature activation.

Comment: I tried your code and it works without problems (except form `[EnumLabel()]`, which I removed).

Comment: Flags is wrong here. Can a card be all 3 types at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure the string compared is "Visa" and not "visa", in which you would also need to pass `true` as last parameter to `Enum.Parse` method..

Comment: Yes card can be of all types. As user may have multiple cards

Comment: Ok I have it working with own value. But how can i pass all the values like Visa,Maestro and Master.As this will tell me what options user have taken.

Answer (score 0):

Friends I found my error. I was trying to parse CreditCardType.Visa instead of Visa.
Thanks all for the help.Sorry for the confusion.